# jobject to jstring or char* conversion

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ex_android_rt_addFriends(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
    jint size, jobjectArray nodes)
 {

jint count = (*env).GetArrayLength(nodes);
  for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
```

**// HERE I'M GETTING OBJECT FROM jobjectArray**

```
jobject element = (*env).GetObjectArrayElement(nodes, i); 

  if((*env).ExceptionOccurred()) {
     break;
  }
//  jstring mStr = ?;
  const char *nativeString = (*env).GetStringUTFChars(mStr, NULL);

 // use your string

  CCLog(" - value - %s -  ", nativeString);

 (*env).ReleaseStringUTFChars(mStr, nativeString);

  (*env).DeleteLocalRef(element);
}
```

I am getting jobject, how do I convert it into a jstring? I have tried:

```
jstring string = (jstring) (*env).GetObjectArrayElement(nodes, 0);
```

with no success.

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
jstring mStr = (*env).GetStringUTFChars(element, 0);
```

and I'm getting

> cannot convert 'const char*' to '_jstring*' in initialization

Comment: have u tried as: `jstring string = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, your_jobject, 0);` ?

Comment: See my edit. I have tried it and I have posted the error too.

Comment: Is `nodes` variable an array of strings? If yes, then `jstring string = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(nodes, i);` should work fine. Otherwise you have error in some other place.

Comment: I was actually sending an ArrayList of strings from Java to jObjectarray. I think that was the issue. I changed it to a string array and it's working now! thanks a lot @Martins Mozeiko. Voted your comment!

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko you should post the solution is an answer!